# I cannot use the Stream API under google cloud endpoints java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, getstream-io

I am trying to make a basic operation as described into the stream api documentation. However when i run my java cloud endpoint project on localhost i have the following error

```js
  Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
 at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:107)
 at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:72)
 at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:117)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:513)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

There what i've already tried

```js
@Api(name = "myapi")
public class Stream {
 ClientConfiguration streamConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
 StreamClient streamClient = new StreamClientImpl(streamConfig, "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    public MyToken getMyToken() throws InvalidFeedNameException{
     String token = streamClient.newFeed("user", "1").getToken();
        MyToken mytoken = new MyToken(token);
        return mytoken;
    }

    public class MyToken {
        public String value;

        public MyToken(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error does not seem related to getstream-io client

Comment: Is this Endpoints Frameworks v2 or the legacy Endpoints?